# how to access state's values in handleClick method inside a functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I want handleCLick to do nothing if selected length >= 4, But when i try to access selected inside handleClick i am getting an empty object. Please help me, im pulling my hairs over this

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    let selectedId = e.target.id;
    if (!selectedId) {
      selectedId = e.target.parentElement.id;
    }
    setSelected((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [selectedId]: true,
      };
    });
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    let resData = null;

    try {
      const res = await axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products");
      if (res.status === 200) {
        resData = res.data.products;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      alert("Something went wrong please check the api");
    } finally {
      if (resData) {
        resData.forEach((ele) => {
          ele.key = ele.id;
          ele.compare = (
            <Button id={ele.id} type="primary" onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
              Compare
            </Button>
          );
        });
        setData(resData);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="main">
          <Sidebar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Products data={data} />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/compareproducts"
              element={<CompareProducts />}
            ></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried setting a variable outside handleClick function with selected states value but that didnt work out.

Comment: I'm not seeing any condition for `selected.length >= 4`, and you are not calling `selected` in your click handler. can you add more clarity to your question or add a sandbox for testing.

Comment: Avoid storing JSX in state. You should use state to define how JSX should be used/rendered. Your issue is that your JSX elements in your state are created on the initial mount of your component, so the onClick function refers to an old version of `handleClick` created on the first render which only knows about the initial state.

Comment: Yes thank you so much. I didnt realize i was calling getData() on initial render.